# Why Error on the fitting functions is too large also curve seems to pass from maximum number of points. How to reduce that error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, power-law

I want to use power law to fit on my data points because I have to calculate the value of v. But the error on my fitting parameters is too large, although curve seems to pass all data points. How to reduce is error?[image]

```
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import scipy 
from scipy import optimize

x_data= np.array([30, 45, 60, 75])
y_data= np.array([0.42597867, 0.26249343, 0.19167837, 0.08116507])

fig = plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)

def ff(L,v,c):
    return (L**(-1/v)+c)


ax2.scatter(x_data, y_data, marker='s',s=4**2,)


pfit,pcov = optimize.curve_fit(ff,x_data,y_data)
print("pfit: ",pfit)
print("pcov: ",pcov.shape)
#print(pcov)
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
x=np.linspace(20,85,1000)

ax2.plot(x,ff(x,*pfit),color='red')`
```

Comment: Can you take repeated measurements at these same data points? It is possible that measurement noise is affecting the data values, and that can be determined by taking repeated measurements.

Comment: I can repeat  the experiment using same L.

Comment: Excellent. That will conclusively determine whether the problem is caused by measurement variability.